# Regex to match a bi-monthly, quarterly, etc., cron job

Tags: javascript, regex, cron, expression

I'm trying to write some javascript regex to validate the monthly portion of a cron job is valid.
(For those who aren't familiar, check out https://crontab.guru)

The cron job monthly portion can specify a job that is
bi-monthly,
every 3 months,
4 months,
or 6 months.

A job that occurs every 4 months could be specified with these 4 formats:

1. * * * */4 *
2. * * * 04,08,12 *
3. * * * 4,8,12
4. * * * 04,8,12
5. * * * 4,08,12

The regex for the first format could look like: `([*][/][2346])` which can be boolean ORed with the regex to cover the rest.

For the rest, I came up with `(0?[1-9]|1[012])(,(0?[1-9]|1[012]))*` for a complete regex of: `(0?[1-9]|1[012])(,(0?[1-9]|1[012]))*|([*][/][2346])`

but this doesn't seem to work!

Using the regex tester at https://regexr.com/4jp54, one can see that each regex to the right of the first and second boolean OR (`|`) doesn't work as expected such that the two instances `|1[012]` don't seem to work.

So `01,03,5,7,09` would get matched, but `01,03,5,7,09,11` and `4,8,12` would not as the `11` and `12` in each respective expression doesn't get matched.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You could match that format using `^\* \* \* (?:0?[48],0?[48],12|\*\/4)(?: \*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/oAorCl/1

Comment: Regex to use with which tool? There are a lot of different regex dialects.

Comment: I suggest that regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job.  You're trying to validate numeric values by pattern matching, which is like stirring paint with a screwdriver.  Also, you may not even need to write code to do this, as there are crontab validators already written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support every 2, 3, 4, 6 month as stated, including single month such as `* * * 3 *`, and odd month such as `* * * 3,7,11 *` you can use this regex (regex is for month portion only) :

```
/^(\*\/[2346]|(0?[1-9]|1[012])(,(0?[1-9]|1[012])){0,5})$/
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start
- `(` - group start

  - `\*\/[2346]` - fraction format, such as `/4`
- `|` - OR

  - `(0?[1-9]|1[012])` - month number `1` ... `12`, optional leading zero
  - `(,(0?[1-9]|1[012])){0,5}` - pattern repeated 0 to 5 times of: `,` followed by month number
- `)` - group end
- `$` - anchor at end

This will validate months such as:

```
*/2
*/4
06             // 1x - once a year
02,10          // 2x - every 6 month
03,07,11       // 3x - every 4 odd month
4,8,12         // 3x - every 4 even month
03,6,9,12      // 4x - every 3 month
02,4,6,8,10,12 // 6x - every 2 month
```

Comment: `/^(\*\/[2346]|(0?[119]|1[012])(,(0?[1-9]|1[012])){0,5})$/`

Assuming you meant:

`/^(\*\/[2346]|(0?[1-9]|1[012])(,(0?[1-9]|1[012])){0,5})$/`

Right?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the typo

Comment: @yalpsid eman: Any other questions? Does this fit your needs?

Comment: I think that should be it ++